# understanding firebase snapshot listener pricing in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, price

I have a course app in which I show the module list for a particular course. each module has its progress. and they sum up as total course progress. here I show progress for each module in this list with the module. 
 My flow is like this: 
I open module complete it.--> A particular progress document for the selected module is updated. 
now when I come back to prev activity and to see an update I made in module reflecting here, I have used snapshot Listeners here. 
So how costing will work for them?
will it only charge fro the updated progress doc? 
what if my user kills the app restarts again.  and comes again on the same course.
as I am using a snapshot listener for courses, modules, and progress .. will it charge me even if the app is restarted but data is not changed. or not?

Comment: Is this a Firebase question?  You should tag it accordingly

Comment: Yes @RyanM it is. I changed title and added firebase word now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it concerns third-party product pricing and support, rather than how to write code for that product, which unfortunately is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more information. You should contact the company for up-to-date information about pricing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as I am using a snapshot listener for courses, modules, and progress, will it charge me even if the app is restarted but data is not changed. or not?

Yes. If you attach a snapshot listener without a condition, it will need to read all documents to determine whether they have changed. So at that point you will be charged for the read operation, although you may not be charged for bandwidth usage for unmodified documents.

If you want to prevent this:

1. Ensure that each document has a field like `lastModified` that has the timestamp of when it was created/last modified.
2. Only query for documents that were modified since your app last ran.
3. Store the time the app last read data in local storage, so that it is persisted between runs of your app.

Comment: I think this answer won't work if you want to delete documents, because your listener will never get noticed of this deletion if it happens while your app wasn't running. The only workaround I could think of is to never delete a document inside FireStore and just set a "deletionFlag" field to true with an updated lastModified date to handle these cases inside your app.